# How to know the diff of what recently changed on files pulled using a pull operation

Tags: git, git-pull

I perform a git pull operation and it fetched via few files. How can I run a diff and understand what really changed in all of those files or a selective set of files within that list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the command `git whatchanged`. It will tell you what files were changed in each commit. If you pass the option `-p`, you can also see which lines are included/excluded in each commit.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can use `git reflog` to show you the hash of the current commit and the previous commit that was checked out.

```
$ git reflog
ffb759d HEAD@{0}: commit: stuff
68dff16 HEAD@{1}: pull: Fast-forward
c718a6a HEAD@{2}: pull: Fast-forward
...
```

As you can see, the most recent change was a commit, and the previous two changes were pulls.  If I want to see the changes in the most recent pull, I can:

```
$ git diff HEAD@{2} HEAD@{1}
```

Or I can look at just the changes to a specific directory,

```
$ git diff HEAD@{2} HEAD@{1} -- example/path
```

You can also browse the changes with `gitk`, `gitg`, `gitx`, et cetera.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`git diff`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff). There's a few places such as [this article](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/01/30/finding-what-has-been-changed.html) or [this one](http://data.agaric.com/get-git-diff-previous-commit) which can get you up to speed on how to use it.